# How to distribute values from list of tuples into array

Tags: python, arrays, tuples

I have list of tuples:

```
foo = [(1, 5), (1, 3), (1, 9), (2, 8), (2, 3), (3, 1)]
```

I am trying to distribute values from foo into `array` of `arrays`, and result should looks like:

```
_result[0] = []
_result[1] = [5, 3, 9]
_result[2] = [8, 3]
_result[3] = [1]
```

And this is my code:

```
_result = [[]]

for x,y in foo:
   _result[x].append(y)
```

But I am getting an error:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

How should I fix it?

## Edit:

- The result does not have to be arranged
- The array at the zero position should contains an empty field

The example is simple, but `foo` can also contain other values such as:

```
foo = [(9, 5), (10, 3), (10, 9), (5, 8), (5, 3), (9, 1)]
```

Result:

```
_result[0] = []
_result[1] = []
_result[2] = []
_result[3] = []
_result[4] = []
_result[5] = [8, 3]
_result[6] = []
_result[7] = []
_result[8] = []
_result[9] = [5, 1]
_result[10] = [3, 9]
```

So all values that are not in position `x` should contain `an empty field` on the given index

Comment: You can't position items in `_result` with for instance `_result[5]` since the size of the list is zero. I don't think this code does what you think it does.

Comment: So @Torxed how should I fix it?

Comment: I can't fix this for you, because there's no logic in your desired outcome. There's no constraints that define why `_result[1]` should contain `[3,5,9]`.

Comment: @Torxed The `x` value of each tuple is the "index" in the outer list. However, using a dict will make much more sense here

Comment: @DeepSpace I see that, but I don't see it in the question. Clarification would be nice.

Comment: @Torxed please check my edit. Is it clear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
length = 0
_result = [[]]

for x, y in foo:
    if x > length:
        for i in range(x - length):
            _result.append([])
        length = length + x
    _result[x].append(y)
```

Problems in your code:

- You can't access an index position in a list where an item doesn't exist.
- You can't append to a list that doesn't exist.

Comment: Only problem I see here, is that the desired outcome doesn't match (the values aren't sorted as it seams to be in the OP's outcome)

Comment: Okay, I missed that they were sorted. But this solves the issue that he raised in his question re. the index error.

Comment: Correct, just to clarify, I did not down vote. But I saw the issue - but then again, OP never specified any constraints so technically your solution is "correct" : )

Comment: Please check my edit. The zero position should contain an empty field

Comment: @Alechandro I've edited my answer to do exactly as you need

Comment: Not exactly, what about if `foo = [(45, 5), (49, 3), (32, 9), (34, 8), (12, 3), (48, 1)]`

Comment: @Alechandro that was never specified in your question. Anyway, I've edited my answer to do what you want

Comment: Iterating 3 times seems excessive. Quoting Raymond Hettinger, "there must be a better way" :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use a `dict` here.

**Ex:**

```
foo = [(1, 5), (1, 3), (1, 9), (2, 8), (2, 3), (3, 1)]
result = {}
for k, v in foo:
    result.setdefault(k, []).append(v)

print(result) # -->{1: [5, 3, 9], 2: [8, 3], 3: [1]}
```

You can also use `collections.defaultdict` instead of `setdefault`